# Oracle PL\SQL to Update Data with the 2nd minimum values between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following problem related industrial pump readings. A pump usually have  a meter that keeps the record of volume of material processed by that specific pump. Sometimes the meter needs to be replaced with a entirely new meter (meter reading starts with 0) or an old working meter (meter reading can be more than 0). I have a dataset that keeps maintenance record of the pump with meter readings.
And the indication of a meter change is only when we have data in OLD_METER_READING column, otherwise it is blank.
In ideal scenario the data looks like following:

```
PUMP_NO  INSPECTION_DATE MAINTENANCE_TASK  METER_READING  OLD_METER_READING TOTAL_PUMP_LIFE 
11        11-AUG-2000            A             12489                             12489
11        14-JUL-2001            B             14007                             14007
11        03-SEP-2002            Y             0            14007                14007
11        03-SEP-2002            C             0            14007                14007
11        03-SEP-2002            B             0            14007                14007
11        04-JUN-2003            A             1200                              16007 
11        21-DEC-2003            A             8000                              22007
11        23-FEB-2004            Y             0            10000                24007
11        26-MAY-2004            B             10                                24017
11        26-MAY-2004            P             20                                24027
11        26-MAY-2004            R             300                               24307
11        04-OCT-2004            B             2312                              26319
11        31-MAR-2005            A             2889                              26896
11        06-NOv-2006            V             5000                              29007
11        14-JUL-2008            T             0            7000                 31007
```

However in many cases the Pump technician will make a mistake in loging METER_READING during change of meter. So the data may end up looking like:

```
PUMP_NO  INSPECTION_DATE MAINTENANCE_TASK METER_READING  OLD_METER_READING TOTAL_PUMP_LIFE 
11        11-AUG-2000             A            12489                            12489
11        14-JUL-2001             B            14007                            14007
11        03-SEP-2002             Y            0            14007                14007
11        03-SEP-2002             C            0            14007                14007
11        03-SEP-2002             B            0            14007                14007
11        04-JUN-2003             A            1200                              16007 
11        21-DEC-2003             A            8000                              22007 
11        23-FEB-2004             Y            0            10000                24007
11        26-MAY-2004             B            10000                             34007
11        26-MAY-2004             P            10000                             34007
11        26-MAY-2004             R            10000                             34007
11        04-OCT-2004             B            2312                              26319
11        31-MAR-2005             A            2889                              26896
11        06-NOV-2006             V            5000                              29007
11        14-JUL-2008             T            0           7000                  31007
```

The mistake in the 2nd set of data is that the technician rather than loging the actual METER_READING used last METER_READING from old meter as the new METER_READING on the day of 26-MAY-2004. However, correct METER_READING was logged again from 04-OCT-2004. We have numerous occasion where for a specific pump (PUMP_NO) we will have erroneous METER_READING entered in the database after a meter change event. It is also creating wrong and confusing value for the TOTAL_PUMP_LIFE. 
So, to correct the data we want to add another column in the table and update the table with a Oracle Procedure where the procedure will check the METER_READING field with the following logic:

1. check the data between two subsequent meter change event. (for example, in this case between 1st meter 03-SEP-2002 and 2nd meter change-23-FEB-2004. And again between 2nd meter change-23-FEB-2004 and 3rd meter change 14-JUL-2008).
2. if METER_READING between any of these period is higher at prior date compared to METER_READING on a prior date then update the higher METER_READING with the 2nd lowest value (0 and 2312 are the 2 lowest, so update with 2312) in that period.

So, the period between first 2 meter changes will pass and no update will be necessary.However, in the 2nd set of the date all the values (10000) in the METER_READING column for 26-MAY-2014 will be updated with the value of 2312.

I am not sure how to write a PL\SQL to do the compare the values between two events and also how to update the value of a prior date (if higher value found in the METER_READING column) with a lower value between that period.

Database: Oracle SQL 11g

Comment: You must post what you had tried so far and whas the problem you are facing rather expecting someone to write code for you

Comment: How are you ordering records that occur on the same day?  How do you identify what is a meter change?

Comment: @Del , Usually there is no specific ordering rule for records of the same day. And the way to identify a meter change is  we get data in the OLD_METER_READING  column and METER_READING  starts with 0 again. However, in some meter change event, the newly installed may already have existing reading >0, in that case the METER_READING  will start from that value. But the most important indicator is having data in the OLD_METER_READING  column.

Comment: What is the additional column you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

So in looking at your problem, I don't know that you need to resort to PL/SQL.  The following query should help you identify which records are in need of updating:

```sql
SELECT m.*, 
       MIN(meter_reading) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY m.pump_no 
               ORDER BY m.inspection_date
               RANGE BETWEEN NVL((SELECT min(n.inspection_date)-m.inspection_date
                                  FROM maintenance n
                                  WHERE n.inspection_date > m.inspection_date),
                                  0) FOLLOWING 
                      AND NVL((SELECT min(n.inspection_date)-m.inspection_date-1
                               FROM maintenance n
                               WHERE n.old_meter_reading IS NOT NULL
                               AND n.inspection_date > m.inspection_date),
                              0) FOLLOWING) AS MIN_READING_FOLLOWING
FROM maintenance m
ORDER BY m.inspection_date, old_meter_reading ASC NULLS LAST;
```

I created a SQLFiddle to demonstrate the query. ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd7d98/20/0))

The analytic MIN function is looking at all rows between the next date a read was performed AND the next meter change to see if any of them have a value which is less than the current read.

You could use this as part of an update statement.  As for TOTAL_PUMP_LIFE, it might be easiest to recalculate that after you've corrected the meter_readings as part of a separate operation.

**Edit 1: Adding PL/SQL to make updates**

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_readings IS
    SELECT m.*, 
           MIN(meter_reading) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY m.pump_no 
                   ORDER BY m.inspection_date
                   RANGE BETWEEN NVL((SELECT min(n.inspection_date)-m.inspection_date
                                      FROM maintenance n
                                      WHERE n.inspection_date > m.inspection_date), 
                                      0) FOLLOWING 
                          AND NVL((SELECT min(n.inspection_date)-m.inspection_date-1
                                   FROM maintenance n
                                   WHERE n.old_meter_reading IS NOT NULL
                                   AND n.inspection_date > m.inspection_date),
                                  0) FOLLOWING) AS MIN_READING_FOLLOWING
    FROM maintenance m
    ORDER BY m.inspection_date, old_meter_reading ASC NULLS LAST;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c_readings LOOP
    IF rec.meter_reading > rec.min_reading_following THEN
      UPDATE maintenance m
      SET m.meter_reading = rec.min_reading_following
      WHERE m.pump_no = rec.pump_no
      AND m.inspection_date = rec.inspection_date
      AND m.maintenance_task = rec.maintenance_task;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You'll need to either `COMMIT` when this is done or add it to the code.

Comment: thanks a lot,its almost of what i want but as you can see in SQLFiddle, the suggested SQL is shifting values up the dates, e.g. between 2004-02-23 and 2004-10-04 all updated Meter Reading should be 2312 (since there is a higher value in a prior date), however for 2004-10-04 the updated value by the SQL is 2889. the METER_READING  from 2004-10-04 to 2006-11-06 all are correct, so the update meter reading for those date will be same. It is only when for a prior date there is a higher value after a Meter change then we are correcting that with the minimum value before another meter change.

Comment: @tintin Yeah, I figured you could add that logic in.  Although you may still end up having to loop over this in PL/SQL.  I'll add some logic into the answer.

Comment: @tintin, I really wanted to avoid the PL/SQL but I kept getting errors on the update.  So instead of blowing up the update clause to like 200 rows, this was easier.  This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what u need to do is something like this:

```
update MyTable mt1
set value = (select min(value)  
           from MyTable2 mt2
         where mt1.id = mt2.id  --your relation
           and value NOT IN (select min(value)  
                               from MyTable2 mt3
                               where mt2.id = mt3.id))
```

With this update u are getting the min value and not taking the min value original with the NOT IN.